# How to help a 3 year old to speak?

Tags: toddler, speech

My child is 2 year 10 months. He is not speaking by his own. If I ask him "What do you want apple or banana?" he answers me: "apple banana". He is not able to understand me. Some kids call him: "come let us play" and he is not able to understand it. Is this normal?. But he is able to say rhymes, number, shapes, colors, etc. But he doesn't or rarely understand what I and others are speaking. If a person calls his name and says hello, he is telling his own name and hello. Is it normal? Can I have some tips to improve his language development?

Comment: To me, as a parent, this should be of concern. By 3 years old, few kids are billing conversationalists, but if would expect them to be able to carry on a conversation. This looks like a place your family physician or pediatrician needs to be involved

Comment: My family physician told me to wait for 3 months ,as he is new to prekindergarden now.Lets see how he mingles with other children.As he is not replying to other children of same age group.A child asks me whether he is deaf.I am worried and so I asked your suggestions.He is able to identify things.Even though dont know to play he will enjoy by running back of kids.

Comment: This is not normal in the US, nor can I imagine a culture in which this would be normal. Waiting 3 months probably won't do irreparable harm, but it's ill advised. He needs to be tested, beginning with hearing and ending with an answer. It's possible that he may not be neurotypical, and the sooner that's diagnosed and dealt with, the better.

Comment: Thanks for your love towards him.To which specialist should I consult.Other thing is that he is alone with me and all our relations are little far away from us.Whether being alone for 2 .6 years may be a problem?Can it be diagnosed

Comment: Nilah, Ideally your family doctor would start to coordinate the specialists you need to see (and in which order you should see them). If they don't feel inclined to do this, ask for a full hearing evaluation first. If the child is unable to comply with simple instructions, the testers have usually seen enough kids to know when it's more than a hearing problem and will report back to your doctor with (hopefully) recommendations for further tests.

Comment: Yes, autism can be diagnosed in 2 year olds (18 months if serious) and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a child generally learns language is by hearing other people talking. Teaching him the rhymes, colors, numbers, etc. is useful for later but does not help his overall language ability at this time. It is likely as the physician says that he will pick it up at school, but you can help by speaking as much as you can at home around him, not necessarily to him directly. If there are other people living with you, it will help him for you to speak to them in his presence just as much as speaking to him will help him.